# add texture to colored object

Tags: texturing

I want to apply this partly transparent png texture to one surface of the cube without losing the red color. How do I do that? 
[image]

When I click on face texture the texture is visible on the surface but the rest of the object becomes black:
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what render engine you are using.

Comment: @cmomoney looking at the screen capture he posted it's safe to say he is using blender render.

Comment: Your transparent .png isn't exactly what is known as a texture in blender world. I feel that this question is similar and might help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46424/18166

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done ...

1 Create a cube.
2 Copy a face of the cube you want to have your transparent graphics on.
3 Move the face a little outward so that it does not share the same 3d space with the original face.
4 Create 2 material, a red one and a transparent one.
5 Remember to turn off cast shadow for the Transparent material.
6 Apply the red material to the cube.
7 Apply the transparent material to the copied face.

Attached is the file I have created for your reference.

[image]